# How can I access a ManyToManyField in the save method of a model?

Tags: django, django-models

I know that there's no way I'm the first to ask this question, but I cannot find the answer so please don't eat me.

If I have a `model` with a `field` that is a `ManyToManyField`; I know that I can get the selected objects **prior to the save** but this isn't helpful if the selected objects have changed.

**`models.py`**:

```
class AddOn(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Invoice(models.Model):
    additional_options = models.ManyToManyField(AddOn)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().save()
        # this prints the objects that were selected prior to the save.
        # this isn't helpful if the selected objects have changed.
        print(self.additional_options.all())
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the way you worded your question, I think you are confused about what is actually happening behind the scenes with a `ManyToManyField` (I will refer to this as `M2M` from now on),  so I will attempt to explain it, with the following models:

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

When we declare a `M2M` field, behind the scenes Django creates a *through model* which in this case looks like this:

```
class ThroughModel(models.Model):
    topping = models.ForeignKey(Topping)
    pizza models.ForeignKey(Pizza)
```

This is used to link the models together, and isn't stored in the database, unless you use the `through` keyword in the `M2M` field to create your own.

Before you can actually link the `Pizza` and `Topping` models in the `M2M`, you 
**must** already have instances saved:

```
>>> t1 = Topping(name='pepperoni')
>>> t2 = Topping(name='sausage')
>>> t3 = Topping(name='ham')
>>> Topping.objects.bulk_create([
>>> t1, t2, t3
>>> ])
>>>
>>> pizza = Pizza(name='meat lovers')
```

Now, how can we add data to the `M2M` field?  Like this:

```
>>> pizza.toppings.add(t1, t2, t3)
```

But as is, this would raise:

> ValueError: 'Pizza' instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.

Because the `pizza` instance **wasn't saved**.

```
>>> pizza.save()
>>> pizza.toppings.add(t1, t2, t3)
>>>
>>> print('no error thrown now!')
```

You can also add `toppings` by passing in a primary key instead of an instance:

```
>>> pk = Toppings.objects.first().pk
>>> pk
1
>>> pizza = Pizza.objects.create(name='pepperoni pizza')
>>> pizza.toppings.add(pk)
```

Finally, to get the `toppings` from a given pizza instance:

```
>>> pizza.toppings.all()
<QuerySet [<Toppings: Toppings object (1)>, <Toppings: Toppings object (2)>, <Toppings: Toppings object (3)>]>
```

It's important to note that fetching the values from a `M2M` **require** 2 database queries, and there really isn't a way around this.

Lastly, to actually answer your question, you can do something like this to access a `M2M` field inside of `save`:

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)

    def save(self, *args): # args will be M2M data
        super().save() # now that the instance is saved, we can access toppings
        if args:
            self.toppings.add(*args)

        print(self.toppings.all())
```

Example usage:

```
>>> pizza = Pizza(name='sausage and ham')
>>> pizza.save(2, 3)
<QuerySet [<Toppings: Toppings object (2)>, <Toppings: Toppings object (3)>]>
# this is from the print inside of save
```

My example models come from the [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) section of the docs, but I'd recommend reading through [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) section if you want to learn more about `ManyToManyFields`.

Comment: I appreciate the explanation but I do understand that there needs to be saved instances of the `ManyToManyField` model in order to be added to the related model. I overcomplicated the question by using a `ManyToManyField`. My question would also apply to a scenario where instead of a `ManyToManyField`, you had a `CharField` that used the `choices` parameter.

Comment: @Ryan I guess I'm still confused by your question then.  If you are trying to access the `M2M` during an update, you can simply call `self.toppings.all()` in the save like in my answer?

Comment: When I call `super().save()` inside of the `save` method and then try to access `self.additional_options.all()`, I am still getting the list prior to the save.

Comment: @Ryan I'm not able to reproduce this.  Can you please add a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is there a solution to this yet? I am facing the same problem. Even after calling `super().save()`, I still get the previous value.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `m2m_changed` signals. here is my solution

```
# models.py

class Recipient(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class CommsGroup(models.Model):
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Recipient)
```

```
# signals.py

from django.db.models.signals import m2m_changed

@receiver(m2m_changed, sender=CommsGroup.recipients.through)
def create_comms_group(sender, instance, action, **kwargs):
    if action == 'post_add':
        print(instance.recipients.all())
```